# Scrapy - Deny rules are ignored

Tags: python, scrapy

in my scapy web crawler project, I have links like that:

https://www.maxblue.de/maerkte-analysen/nachrichten-news/boersenkalender.termine.html?DATE=2089-06-15

I try to filter out those links with adding "DATE=" to the deny rules:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=[r'blank\\.html',
                              r'isin\\=',
                              r'_frame\\.htm',
                              r'actionbar',
                              r'actionframe',
                              r'popup_times_and_sales',
                              r'ID_NOTATION',
                              r'suchergebnis',
                              r'DATE\\=',
                              r'NOTATION\\=']),
```

However, like with "NOTATION=" too, the sites are crawled anyway, but filtering seems to work with the "popup_times..." string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `DATE=` without \\ ? Or with single \  ?

Comment: Thank you furas for pointing me into the right direction! I had not really understood the python regex syntax; masking characters which should not be masked. It worked without the \\. I'm still too deep in the perl world.